# Mapping data in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to pass data to a pipeline with a map which the point is just to provide app name and environment and I will get all the other data I need to my main pipeline

I'm passing data to my deployment pipeline like so:

```
env.project_info= [
  git_path:"",
  git: "",
  config_branch: "",
  team_name: ""
]
```

Which works but I want to change it.
I'm trying to change it into a map in which I will pass only the app name and env and it will pass me all the data above.

Does someone have any tips on how to do it?

Comment: Please update with an example of what you want to achieve versus what you have achieved as it is currently unclear what your objective is here.

Comment: Hi the block code is what I have currently my goal is to pass just the env and app name from my main Pipeline to This one and retrieve all the data above. The point is to make it in a map format